# what is wrong with error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')

Tags: c++

for output from one line of my code

```
double _double = pow(((15) ^ 17)/11 ^ 1.5,2)/9.8;
```

when I try to compile it, it returns error: invalid operands to binary expression   ('double' and 'double')
I think both 15 ^ 17 and 11 ^ 1.5 would be double, so why it gave me this error?

Comment: `^` is not power, it is logical `xor`. The problem is `... ^ 1.5`.

Comment: Why do you think this should work?

Comment: why are you doing pow and then think that `^` is the power operator?

Comment: just try it to see if ^ works also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler gives you an error because `^` in C++ does not do what you think it does. It is a XOR operator, not a power operator, and it works only on integral data types. For example, `15 ^ 17` is `30`:

```
    01111 // 15
XOR 10001 // 17
---------
    11110 // 30
```

In fact, C++ lacks the power operator altogether. You should use [`std::pow(double,double)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) instead:

```
double _double = pow(pow(15, 17)/pow(11, 1.5), 2)/9.8;
```

Comment: can I do it like this ? double _double = pow(pow(15, 17)/pow(11, 1.5), 2)/9.8;

Comment: @QifengSun Yes, in fact, that's the right way to do it, because power has higher priority than division.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot operate two doubles with `XOR` (`^`). It only works with `int`, `long`, `bool`, `short`, `char` and their variations. No floating-point datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
double _double = pow(((15) ^ 17)/11 ^ 1.5,2)/9.8;
```

The `^` operator is the logical *exclusive or* operator.

To exponentiate numbers, use `pow`, like you do.